# Change UIImageView color like UILabel's highlighted property when row is selected?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

The `highlighted` property of `UILabel` changes the label's text color when a `UITableViewCell` is selected. Is it possible to do something similar for a `UIImageView`?

[image: "Highlighted" property for a label]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, UIImageView color can be set, using highlighted image. It has two types of properties to images. Normal and Highlighted image.

This options are available in attribute inspector in Interface file (storyboard/XIB).

Another option is available for vector images, where you can set tintColor for template types of image asset.

Swift 3
You can also set both properties programatically.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(<set your initialiser>)
imageView.image = //Your normal image
imageView.highlightedImage = //You highligted image
```

Upon your tableview row selection status, change state of image from normal to highlighted and vice-versa. imageView.isHighlighted = true/false

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   imageView.isHighlighted = true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    imageView.isHighlighted = false
}
```

[image]